# NSPredicate for NSNumber property of NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios6, nspredicate

I have `NSNumber * year` property of `NSManagedObject`, it's type in data model is `Integer 16`.

I try to check with `NSPredicate` for this year, but can't find the right one.

What I tried:

```
NSPredicate *p = nil;
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *yearNo = [nf numberFromString:term];
if (yearNo) {
    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(cars.year == %i)", yearNo.intValue];
}
```

I also tried:

```
NSPredicate *p = nil;
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSNumber *yearNo = [nf numberFromString:term];
if (yearNo) {
    p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(cars.year == %@)", yearNo];
}
```

In both cases app crashes.

Comment: Show us the fetch request or the crash log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you provide more details for your model, we could help you.

But I think the problem is due to `cars`. If `cars` is to-many you need a modifier for this

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY cars.year == %@", yearNo];
```

Comment: My guess was that he wants to search for `Car` objects with a given `year`, in that case the predicate would be just `"year == %@", yearNo`.

Comment: @MartinR It's also possible. Add your answer if you want ;)

Answer (score 8):

As @flexaddicted already said, you have not supplied sufficient information, e.g. for which entity the fetch request is made.

If you want to fetch `Car` objects with a given `year`, the predicate is just

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"year == %@", yearNo]
```